# Python - Google App Engine - Methods in Django template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, methods, django-templates

I'm coming from a Rails programming experience.

I'm coding an app in Python on Google App Engine with Django templates.

I can't call strftime("%I:%M %p") on a datetime.

In my main.py file I have:

```
import datetime
....
class Report(db.Model):
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

I pass all the reports to the template and in the template I have:

```
{% for report in reports %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ report.date.strftime("%I:%M %p") }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I know I have a datetime object because I can do:

```
{{ report.date.day }}
```

or:

```
{{ report.date.minute }}
```

Just fine and they return what they are supposed to return.

When I do have:

```
 {{ report.date.strftime("%I:%M %p") }}
```

I get the error:

`raise TemplateSyntaxError, "Could not parse the remainder: %s" % token[upto:]
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ("%I:%M %p")`

How do I get strftime to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Django template engine doesn't support passing arguments to methods like that. To accomplish the same thing, try using [the `date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
{{ report.date|date:"f A" }}
```

(Edited: fixed the syntax for the date string, because I'm stupid.)

Comment: Thanks!

I did `{{ report.date|date:"f A" }}`

Answer (score 1):

The Django template system is "[meant to express presentation, not program logic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/)" that's why it "is not simply Python embedded into HTML".

Only tags and filters are supported by default. That's why you needed to find a filter similar to the function you pointed out, as @Dougal did.
The other option would be to make a [custom template tag or filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), but in this case would be an overkill.